# Lambda expression issue in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, lambda, java-8, netbeans-8

I am having an issue with my Lambda expression in Netbeans 8.0 and am wondering if I did something wrong, or Netbeans or the javac compiler does it wrong.

I have the following code:

```
public interface HandView extends View<Hand> {
    void onCardAdded(final Card card);

    void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex);

    void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo);

    public static HandView merge(final HandView... handViews) {
        return new HandView() {
            @Override
            public void onCardAdded(final Card card) {
                Arrays.stream(handViews).forEach(handView -> handView.onCardAdded(card));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex) {
                Arrays.stream(handViews).forEach(handView -> handView.onCardPlayed(cardIndex));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo) {
                Arrays.stream(handViews).forEach(handView -> handView.onCardsSwapped(cardIndexOne, cardIndexTwo));
            }
        };
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface OnCardAddedListener extends HandView, Consumer<Card> {
        @Override
        default void accept(final Card card) {
            onCardAdded(card);
        }

        @Override
        void onCardAdded(final Card card);

        @Override
        default void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex) { }

        @Override
        default void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo) { }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface OnCardPlayedListener extends HandView, IntConsumer {
        @Override
        default void accept(final int cardIndex) {
            onCardPlayed(cardIndex);
        }

        @Override
        default void onCardAdded(final Card card) { }

        @Override
        void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex);

        @Override
        default void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo) { }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface OnCardsSwappedListener extends HandView {
        @Override
        default void onCardAdded(final Card card) { }

        @Override
        default void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex) { }

        @Override
        void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo);
    }
}
```

Which I then use with:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
HandView handView = card -> counter.incrementAndGet();
```

Netbeans gives the following message:

```
incompatible types: HandView is not a functional interface
    multiple non-abstract methods found in interface HandView
```

Then I'll decide to cast it manually:

```
HandView handView = 
    (HandView.OnCardAddedListener)card -> counter.incrementAndGet();
```

Now it warns me that the cast is redundant.

When I compile it within Netbeans 8.0 with the original version, it compiles fine without any *compilation* (or runtime) errors. Who is at fault now?

I would say that `card -> counter.incrementAndGet()` implements the *SAM* `HandView.OnCardAddedListener`, which then is a subtype of `HandView`, so it should be correct, right?

Comment: Still working on your card game, eh? :) FYI, the version without cast does not compile in Eclipse for me either (type inference is probably not smart enough). However, the version with cast does not show any redundancy warning.

Comment: I’m a bit confused about your statement about which version of your code did work or didn’t work with which compiler. Trying myself with Eclipse, Netbeans 8.0, and javac of jdk1.8.0_05, I encounter the same behavior with all of them, needing a cast and not getting a warning about the cast being redundant. And that’s what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message you get from Netbeans is right:

```
public interface HandView extends View<Hand> {
    void onCardAdded(final Card card);

    void onCardPlayed(final int cardIndex);

    void onCardsSwapped(final int cardIndexOne, final int cardIndexTwo);

    (...)
}
```

This is indeed **not** a FunctionalInterface.

Regarding this line:

```
HandView handView = 
    (HandView.OnCardAddedListener)card -> counter.incrementAndGet();
```

I would write this as:

```
HandView.OnCardAddedListener handView = card -> counter.incrementAndGet();
```

Which I would expect the compiler to handle better, without any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of `@FunctionalInterface` as much as possible.

If you annotate your `HandView` interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HandView extends View<Hand> {
```

you will get a compilation error that the `HandView` interface is not functional, ie. it declares more than one `abstract` method.

---

When you cast it

```
HandView handView = 
(HandView.OnCardAddedListener)card -> counter.incrementAndGet();
```

it should work. The lambda expression in that context, ie. where a `HandView.OnCardAddedListener` is expected, will see `OnCardAddedListener` which is a `@FunctionalInterface`. Therefore an instance can be created from the lambda expression.

Additional information for completeness: Consider that a functional interface can have any number of default or static methods, see for example java.util.function.Function.